# how to make checkbox work in modalroute class

Tags: flutter, dart

hi i have a modal route which open this from bottom to top and make the barrier color opacity so i love it but the problem is the checkbox isn't working!

[image]

```
class FilterSearch extends ModalRoute{

    bool chkSearchbySkill = false;

    @override
    Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 700);

    @override
    bool get opaque => false;

    @override
    bool get barrierDismissible => false;

    @override
    Color get barrierColor => Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5);

    @override
    String get barrierLabel => null;

    @override
    bool get maintainState => true;

    @override
    Widget buildPage(BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,) {
        // This makes sure that text and other content follows the material style
        return Material(
            type: MaterialType.transparency,
            // make sure that the overlay content is not cut off
            child: SafeArea(
                child: _buildOverlayContent(context),
            ),
        );
    }

    Widget _buildOverlayContent(BuildContext context) {
        return Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 50),
                            color: Colors.grey[50],
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                    Checkbox(
                                       value: this.chkSearchbySkill, 
                                       onChanged: (bool value){setState((){chkSearchbySkill = value;});},)
                                    ]))));}


    @override
    Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
        var begin = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
        var end = Offset.zero;
        var curve = Curves.ease;

        var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

        return SlideTransition(
            position: animation.drive(tween),
            child: child,
        );
    }
}
```

how to make checkboxes work!!

another question if i use bottomsheet instead of modal route does i get the same result (the opacity background) and will the checkboxes work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your **ModalRoute** class has the capability to trigger a widget rebuild through the **setState** method. For this, you should wrap the **Align** widget you're returning out of the **_buildOverlayContent** if you want to encapsulate the checkbox state within this method, as in:

```dart
Widget _buildOverlayContent(BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) {
            return Align(
              ...
            );
          }
        );
}
```

And then, after clicking, the checkbox reflects the change:

[image]

Suggestion: rewrite your FilterSearch class as a **StatefulWidget**, and just use it as the content of the **showDialog** or even as the content of the **showModalBottomSheet**. My two cents.